# entity framework , PK and FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework

После добавления данных в CustomerId записывается NULL, почему?

[image: после добавления данных в CustomerId записывается NULL , почему?]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    // Ссылка на заказы
    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }

    // Ссылка на покупателя
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public void Execute()
{
    using (Technic context = new Technic())
    {
        context.Customers.Add(new Customer() { Name = this.name, Email = this.email, Age = this.age });
        context.Orders.Add(new Order() { ProductName = this.productname, Quantity = this.quantity });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Record is Created");
}
```

Comment: Вы всегда удаляете [свои вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/981463/213987), когда получаете ответ в комментариях - чтобы никто не мог написать ответ и дать возможность другим участникам зайти из поиска и увидеть готовый ответ на похожий вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего так происходит потому, что экземпляр `Order` никак не ссылается на экземпляр `Customer`, т.е. между ними нет никакой связи. Другими словами, Вам нужно эту связь создать. Не уверен, но попробуйте так:

```cs
using (Technic context = new Technic()) {
    Customer customer = new Customer() {
        Name = this.name,
        Email = this.email,
        Age = this.age
    };
    Order order = new Order() {
        ProductName = this.productname,
        Quantity = this.quantity,
        Customer = customer
    };
    context.Customers.Add(customer);
    context.Orders.Add(order);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: всё работает спасибо

Comment: @SabaKoghuashvili если ответ решил Вашу проблему, то отметьте ответ как решение и это будет более чем спасибо :)